# Is there any way to test New google play referrer api without publishing the app in Google play store?

Tags: android, installation, google-play-services, install-referrer

Recently Google released Google Play Install Referrer API (announcement).

there are various duplicates to this question but no clarity regarding it.

need  a exact  way of testing this code before publishing.

```
InstallReferrerClient mReferrerClient

mReferrerClient = InstallReferrerClient.newBuilder(this).build();
mReferrerClient.startConnection(new InstallReferrerStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInstallReferrerSetupFinished(int responseCode) {
        switch (responseCode) {
            case InstallReferrerResponse.OK:
                // Connection established
                break;
            case InstallReferrerResponse.FEATURE_NOT_SUPPORTED:
                // API not available on the current Play Store app
                break;
            case InstallReferrerResponse.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE:
                // Connection could not be established
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInstallReferrerServiceDisconnected() {
        // Try to restart the connection on the next request to
        // Google Play by calling the startConnection() method.
    }
});
```

Comment: publish on beta or alpha.. make couple of test users for that app and you can test it with those users

Comment: done but   if we are still getting  utm source %20set and same for utm meduim.how can i fix the  %20set issue .do i need some exact url format?

Answer (score 0):

For testing/debugging purposes you can use the following way:

1. Open the referral link on your device (it will redirect to Play Market). **Do not install app from play market!**
2. Do not close the Play Market application
3. Execute "**Run app**" or "**Build**" process from Android Studio
4. You will get all data like your app installed from referral link